# How to change default option for UV selection?

Tags: uv, selection-tools

How might i change this 'Select Linked Pick' option to not, by default, have the 'Extend' option turned on? In 2.79 it didn't operate like this and so that is my workflow, so this keeps throwing a stutter into my unwrapping. These more obvious options in 2.8 are great, but I'm just wondering how to edit their default settings.

[image: se]

Answer (score 0):

Just untick option in Preferences... (I searched by key, which is 'L', and scrolled down to UV Editor).

[image]